# What is wrong in my Blocking Queue implementation

Tags: c++, concurrency, mutex

```
// Thread-safe Queue
template<class T>
class BlockingQueue {
    public:
        BlockingQueue() {
            isempty.lock();
        }
        void push(T obj) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
            data.push(obj);
            isempty.unlock(); // Queue is no longer empty
        }
        T pop() {
            isempty.lock(); // Acquired lock means I queue is not empty -- or wait until
                        // Calling isempty first so that there is no deadlock if pop is blocked on this
                        // and meanwhile push is called my another thread 
            mtx.lock();
            auto x = data.front();
            data.pop();
            if(!empty()) 
            {
                mtx.unlock(); 
                isempty.unlock(); // Queue is still not empty
            }
            else {
                mtx.unlock();     // Queue is empty don't unlock "isempty"
            }
            return x;
        }
    private:
        bool empty() {
            return data.empty();
        }
        size_t size() {
            return data.size();
        }
        std::queue<T> data;
        std::mutex mtx; // Mutex to stop data-race
        std::mutex isempty; // Mutex to block on empty Queue
};
```

I've recently begun learning about concurrency and attempted to create a producer-consumer example by implementing a blocking queue in C++. I haven't explored semaphores or read-write locks yet and focused solely on using mutexes for synchronization. Could someone please review my implementation and help me understand why this is wrong.

Comment: Two pushes -> double isempty.unlock() -> undefined behavior.

Comment: Recommendation: Update the question to include why you believe it is wrong. What behaviours are you observing? This will make the question much more useful to future askers in determining whether or not they have a similar-enough problem to be worth their time reading and implementing the answers.

Comment: Side note: You're opening up the possibility for mutexes to be locked in one thread and unlocked in another thread. This a bad idea as noted [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock)

Comment: Come to think of it, the entire point is to lock in one thread and unlock in another. This is a pathway to the dark side. Don't do this at all. There is no good outcome from this line of investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [cppreference on `std::mutex::unlock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock):

> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

This hits you two ways I can see (and possibly a few I can't):

`push` has no protection for `isempty.unlock();` to prevent calls while unlocked, nor can it be reasonably implemented. Say you check to see if the mutex is locked, only to find that another thread slips in after the check and locks or unlocks it. Having to protect a mutex with another mutex is a sure sign you're on the road to madness.

Some mutex implementations allow locking in one thread and unlocking in another, but C++'s `std::mutex` does not. POSIX's `pthread` mutexes do not. Win32 mutexes, or at least the ones I know about and use, do not.

What'll happen in C++ and POSIX is Undefined Behaviour. Maybe it will work the way you want, but it's on you to test the  out of the program or prove the behaviour will be you want through implementation notes for your tool chain and target. You'll have to re-prove this regularly as implementation details are subject to change at any time.

Personally, I encountered a mechanism in the serial driver on an embedded system about 20 years back. It worked as designed, but it was a  to debug and prove. I spent hours digging through thousands of lines of code looking for all of the unlocks to find which ones paired up. Don't be *that guy*. If a better-targeted solution like a semaphore or condition variable is available, use them and reserve mutexes for protection of short critical sections.